# Issue faced during Flask-login authorizing per enter

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-login

I using flask-login for authorizing in my site.

If I login once, flask do not offer login again, but I want users to be logged in every time they log on to the site.

P.S.: I try to use `remember=False` in `login_user() function`, but it didn't help.

What can be the correction that need to be done?

Comment: Change your question to sth. like "'Remember me' doesn't work in Flask". Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39938199/flask-login-remember-me-not-working-if-login-managers-session-protection-is-se?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

**I now see case for fresh loging like password change etc** It is provided for by the use of [fresh_login_required](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#fresh-logins)

```
flask_login.login_fresh()
```

This returns True if the current login is fresh. So your views protected with login required you can do something like

```
if not login_fresh():
  #redirect to your login page with a request to reauthenticate
```

or (and am using change-password just as an example you can use it on any and all views that require fresh login everytime)

```
from flask.ext.login import  fresh_login_required
@app.route("/change-password")
@fresh_login_required
def change_password():
    #do stuff here
```

If the user is not authenticated, LoginManager.unauthorized() is called as normal. If they are authenticated, but their session is not fresh, it will call LoginManager.needs_refresh() instead. (In that case, you will need to provide a LoginManager.refresh_view.) which you can do as below as per the [docs](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#fresh-logins)

```
login_manager.refresh_view = "accounts.reauthenticate"
login_manager.needs_refresh_message = (
    u"To protect your account, please reauthenticate to access this page."
)
login_manager.needs_refresh_message_category = "info"
```

If what you are looking at is logging someone out after lets say 5 minutes of inactivity for which [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783025/is-there-an-easy-way-to-make-sessions-timeout-in-flask/11785722#11785722) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760486/resetting-the-expiration-time-for-a-cookie-in-flask/19795394) gives you a very good answer, so you would do it like this

```
 from datetime import timedelta 
 from flask import session, app

 #make the session permanent and set expiry period
 session.permanent = True
 app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=5)

#everytime a user visits, modify the session so that you know they are still active

@app.before_request
    def func():
    session.modified = True
```

You can make the lifetime very small for a start for testing purposes